# Run a 3 Phase machine, on 240v with start & run capacitors

Tags: capacitor, three-phase

Being a Carpenter & Joiner, I must approach "cap in hand" and ask some proper sparkies for assistance in pointing me in the right direction please?  Maybe someone could take a look at the wiring of my Wadkin 10" AGS Tablesaw and hopefully tell me where to begin or perhaps advise me of a good funeral plan?

1. Why has it got Red white & blue wires and only 3 (I thought 3 phase had 4 wires)?
2. Assuming success is possible, what about that foot brake (could I still use it)?
3. What is the purpose of the coil and does it need molegrip extraction?
4. Which wire goes where and why?
5. Which type of capacitor would be the best choice?

All liability is mine and no one who offers suggestions can be responsible, should I fry myself like an overpriced gammon steak!  :-)

Thanks in advance, Kevin Chamberlain.

[image: photo2][image: photo3]
[image: photo 4]
[image: photo5]
[image: photo]
[image: photo]
[image: photo][image: photo][image: photo][image: photo][image: photo]

Comment: From your health and safety point of view I would advise you see a specialist electrical engineering firm who have experience of converting this or similar machines. It is definitely not a DIY project. It will probably require the replacement of the 3 phase motor with a single phase together with the associated control system. Not cheap!

Comment: Look and learn!   Thanks for the post though.

Comment: Why is a solidly Electrical Engineering question off topic on a site entitled *Electrical Engineering*?

Comment: I get the message...  Silly me, asking about electrical engineering!  Suppose I'll have to look for help on a dedicated electrical engineering forum that approves electrical engineering questions!  Thanks to the good guys for your kindness, the rest of you can shove your thumbs up each others arses.  Bye Bye!

Comment: k chambes your question is reasonabe and dont be put off .I did a thing for the university on this in 1983 .I had to simplify and practicalise someones masters thesis so I could run such a motor for one of the technicians to prove things .It worked.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, this is really a common question in some circles- with the cheap availability of inexpensive metal-working machinery in rust-belt areas, lots of people want to take a Bridgeport milling machine or similar and operate it in their garage or basement.

There are basically four approaches, each with advantages and disadvantages.

1. Replace the \$3\phi\$ motor with a single phase-- that generally seems to be an unsatisfactory option. \$3\phi\$ motors are smoother (less torque ripple) smaller and so on.
2. Buy a VFD (Variable Frequency Drive) that can accept single-phase input and output \$3\phi\$ power. Note that **not** all will do that.. there are three kinds- the smallest ones will generally accept single phase at the rated HP. Some will accept \$3\phi\$ input power and can also run from single phase with derating of the HP. Some will only operate with \$3\phi\$ input power. Note that the ones that take single phase have big expensive electrolytic capacitors inside that eventually wear out.
3. Make (or buy) a *rotary phase converter*. This approach uses a surplus \$3\phi\$ motor, generally rated at more than the motor you're trying to power. It simply idles (nothing on the shaft) and effectively generates the missing phases. Since such motors are often available locally for little more than scrap price, it's a viable option and you don't lose anything in starting torque or running smoothness. The idler motor may need to be started with a rope (gives me the willies) or there are more sophisticated ways to do it. This is pretty much the favorite approach with the metalworking contingent, though with the drop in price of surplus and Chinese VFDs, the second option is no longer out of the question even for the frugal.
4. A *static phase converter*. This is the approach you were asking about, except using your existing motor as the idler. You lose starting torque and HP this way, but it will work. The better methods use a voltage sensing relay to remove a starting capacitor.

Note that some folks do some research and find that there are ways to convert two-phase to three-phase (eg. Scott-T transformers), and that tends to degrade into a discussion of why 240V/120V power in North American homes is actually single phase and not true two-phase. Let's not open that can of worms, it is NOT a 5th way!

Now that I've blathered long enough I'm going to point you to some tutorials and suppliers rather than duplicate their excellent information. Also, I know very little of Welsh power, and probably couldn't read the [warning labels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Road_signs_in_Wales) with 12 consonants in a row.

Here is an e-Bay [supplier](http://www.ebay.ca/itm/3-5-Hp-Static-Phase-Converter-Mill-Drill-Lathe-1-2-off-deal-now-on-sale-USA-/191060030239?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2c7c10b31f) of static phase converters. The seller is wnysupply, for when that item expires. At less than $50, even with shipping, it's pretty economical, but he's in the USofA.

Also on eBay [here](http://www.ebay.ca/itm/Rotary-Phase-Converter-Panel-AD5-STK-DIY-5-PH-Convert-1-to-3-PH-Made-in-USA-/390763257913?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item5afb4e2039) is a US supplier of rotary converter panels (the stuff you need outside the free/cheap motor). About $220. An installation video from the same supplier [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Sqa9kWkCWA).

A brief overview of DIY [here](http://www.nojolt.com/how-to-build-a-rotary-phase-converter.shtml). A better overview of both static and rotary DIY converters [here](http://www.homemetalshopclub.org/projects/phconv/phconv.html). You'll find reference to a gent named "[Fitch Williams](http://www.practicalmachinist.com/FitchWConverter.pdf)" in much of the information- he has written a canonical answer to phase converters. Here's a [thread](http://www.practicalmachinist.com/vb/transformers-phase-converters-vfd/rotary-phase-converter-designs-plans-101231/index2.html). Fitch is a great guy and a great engineer, but he's gone through some serious stuff in the past few years and may not be able to help personally.

Now, since I detect a note of reluctance to jump right into the deep end, may I suggest that you find a local chapter of a club of "Model Engineers" (that's what they're called in the UK). They're generally great guys and, aside from being able to whittle an operating steam locomotive out of bits scrap steel- making tools, to make tools, to make tools, they have a great deal of accumulated knowledge on this sort of thing, and someone will probably help you with the conversion. It's not really that big a deal for someone who's comfortable working the the mains. [Here](http://www.nwmes.org.uk/) is one lead on that.

Comment: Welsh power is identical to English, Scottish & Irish, IE 240vac (but maybe our wires are made of sheeps wool?) What do the Red, white and blue wires mean please?  And what does that transformer do please?  Thank you for your kindness, KC!

Comment: Just guessing here, nothing you can rely upon. That nameplate looks useful, but I can't read it at that resolution. They should be L1, L2, L3, but that color code does not match standard UK color codes.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-phase_electric_power . The transformer is probably just to reduce the 380 (?) mains to something more reasonable for the motor starter contactor, lamps and whatever else is (relatively) low voltage.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to forget about running the motor directly off single phase, and to use a 1 phase in, 3 phase out inverter of the appropriate rating for the motor.

This will give you the smoothness of 3 phase drive and additional options (soft start, variable speeds) which are useful in some applications though I don't know about table saws.

Your photos are so small and unreadable that any further advice is impossible, beyond a guess that the motor is possibly delta wound (which would explain the lack of neutral connection). As it's a Wadkin I'm guessing you're in the UK.

[A variety of inverters are available here](http://www.motorsandinverters.co.uk/1Phase-in-3Phase-out/Teco-c22/) as an example of what you are looking for, this link does not constitute  a recommendation of that website. Expect to pay at least the same again to have it safely installed by a
competent electrician.

Comment: It's probably delta wound if it has no neutral?

Comment: Quite right, I actually MEANT to say Delta. Edited...

Comment: Sorry about the little photos.  I took nice big clear ones but had serious trouble uploading them.  I will endeavour to do it correctly this evening.  Thank you for you kindness, kc.